# Simple OpenCV problem

Tags: opencv

Why I try to run the following OpenCV program, it shows the following error :

ERROR:

```
test_1.exe - Application Error

The application failed to initialize properly (0x80000003). 
Click on OK to terminate the application.
```

CODE:

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

int main()
{
IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("C:\\face.bmp");

cvSetImageROI(img, cvRect(100,100, 100, 100));
cvAddS(img, cvScalar(50), img);
cvResetImageROI(img);
cvShowImage("Test", img);

cvWaitKey(0);

return 0;
}
```

When i press F5(im using vs2008express), the program encounters a break point...i have attached a picture...dont know, whether, it will help or not.

[Error Snapshot Link](http://i39.photobucket.com/albums/e179/iamcreasy/error.jpg)

It is not that, only this program is producing this error, but also any kind of image manipulation funciton containing (OpenCV)program is resulting in this sitution. 
Such as : cvSmooth

one last thing, it there any dedicated OpenCV forum or sth like that?

---

I am an administrator.So, yes, ive the permission.

```
a version mismatch.
```

sorry, i didn't get it?Version mismatch with what?

But, i have found the error using dependency walker.

```
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export 
function in a delay-load dependent module.
```

and also found that, it is a common problem, and found some info in the FAQ of DW...

```
Why am I seeing a lot of applications where MPR.DLL shows up in red under 
SHLWAPI.DLL because it is missing a function named WNetRestoreConnectionA? 
I also get a "Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to 
a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module" message.

Function name : WNetRestoreConnectionA
```

But there is no guideline about how to solve it. Though, they say, it is not a problem.

i googled a little and found a suggestion.It says,

```
Turn off your compilers setting to assume you are programming for Win9x. 
(I just lost which setting but it is not that difficult, use a #define...)
```

But i have no idea, how to do that in Visual Studio 2008 express.

Any suggestion how to solve it...

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help with the actual problem you were encountering, but you asked if there was a dedicated OpenCV forum, and the answer is yes - the [OpenCV Yahoo Group](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/).

Answer (score 1):

This usually indicates a problem with a dll; either you don't have permission, or a version is mismatched.  Try running as Administrator to see if it is a permissions problem.  If that doesn't help, try using the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).